# Is there a good Open Source xml ide?

Tags: xml, ide

I've looked around, and I'm surprised that I can't find an Open Source equivalent to Oxygen or XMLSpy.  i.e. A rich XML editor with support for diverse types of validation, XSLT debugging and profiling, and all the other extra bits that make it more than just a text editor with syntax highlighting.

I've seen a few (like [Jaxe](http://jaxe.sourceforge.net/)), that that offer different ways to edit xml documents, but nothing that rolls it all up into an IDE-like application.

I'm sure this means I've missed some very worthy project.  Can anyone point me towards such a thing?

[Addendum]

Although it's interesting to hear about free licences for proprietary software, my question is really about Open Source Applications.

Background: I normally maintain that when looking for software for software development, OSS is the first port of call, as developers quite like "eating their own dog food".  Normally, one needs a compelling reason to look at proprietary software in this domain.  This seems not to be the case regarding XML Editors, and that surprised me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xselerator](https://xselerator.soft112.com/) in Windows has been around for ages and is still my weapon of choice when dealing with both XML and XSLT. It has proved invaluable for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I'd not heard of that app before.

Answer (score 2):

I agree there is definately a gap there, however in my experience most developers muddle through with basic editors, unless they have to do schema design work, or serious XSLT.

Eclipse has various good plugins for working directly with XML, or the IntelliJ community edition is free it has basic xml support but plugins for XML are available.
Last option I've used is JEdit, this has a range of plugins for various XML tasks xPath, XSLT but finding the combination your happy with takes time.

Comment: Yes, finding the right collection of Eclipse plugins could well be the right way to go, but as you say, one must take time to sample all the lemons.

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you want

Liquid's XML Studio - seems it comes as a free community edition.

Comment: Please note that a "free community edition" is not the same as "open source".

Comment: Thats a fair comment, but may be the best option until one comes along